# DevExpress ASPxPivotGrid.CustomCellStyle Event: Change a cell's style based on values of other cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I need to change the background of a cell based on values of multiple cells. Example in Pseudo Code:

```
Percentage = Actual Value / Target Value

IF (Percentage < 33)
 Cell Color = Red
ELSE IF (Percentage < 66)
 Cell Color = Orange
ELSE
 Cell Color = Green
```

I found this:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPivotGridASPxPivotGrid_CustomCellStyletopic

That's nice, but it doesn't show an example of getting a value from another cell in the same row. I need an example and the above link does say it is possible:

"...allows you to customize the appearance of cells dynamically (depending on their 
contents, position, **values of other cells**, etc..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
decimal target = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetFieldValue(fieldTarget));
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value);
decimal percent = (value / target) * 100;
```

where fieldTarget is an instance of a `DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridField`

and then use that value to set the background color..